# Adding slicers for both the rows and columns in a Pivot chart

Tags: excel, pivot-table, slicers

I work with this data:
[link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc4nK.png)

The goal is to create a (bar) chart where I can choose both which week (01, 02, etc.) and which column (sleep, exercise, etc.) it displays. While adding a slicer for *Weeks* solves a part of that problem, I cannot seem to find a way to add a slicer for the column categories. I can add a slicer for a particular column category, like *Sleep*, but that only gives me the option to choose from different numbers for each week inside the table.

Although I realize this could be fixed by simply removing unwanted/adding wanted fields inside the Pivot table, it's not particularly feasible because the end goal is to have a dashboard where one can easily make a selection of different criteria for data filtering. Below is a screenshot of what I'd like the end result to look like, excpept that there'd be an additional slicer that allows me choose which column data I wanted displayed.

[Approximate example of desired end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q9q2.png)